# onBlur Area Code

Tags: javascript

What I am trying to do is check to see if they entered 3 numbers for Area Code and then when they enter 3 move to the next field.  3 numbers must be entered.  I have tried it several ways.

Updated:
I am also trying to make sure they put 3 a required 3 digits in the area code, phone prefix and 4 numbers in the  phone suffix.

I think I should not be using the onblur... I think...

Form Code:

---

```
            <div class="formPhone" style="float:left;">
            (<input name="areaCode" id="areaCode"  type="text"  maxlength="3"
                onkeyup="validateNextField(this,3,phonePrefix);" 
                onblur="validateFixedLengthNumericField(this,3);"  
                style="font-size:11px; width:20px;"  title="Area Code" autocomplete="off">) 
            <input name="phonePrefix" id="phonePrefix" type="text" 
                onkeyup="validateNextField(this,3,phoneSuffix);" 
                onblur="validateFixedLengthNumericField(this,3);"  
                style="font-size:11px; width:20px;" maxlength="3"  title="Phone Prefix" autocomplete="off">-
            <input name="phoneSuffix" id="phoneSuffix" type="text"  maxlength="4" 
                onkeyup="validateNextField(this,3,phoneExtension);" 
                onblur="validateFixedLengthNumericField(this,4);"  
                style="font-size:11px; width:25px;" title="Phone Suffix" autocomplete="off"> 
            ext: 
            <input name="phoneExtension" id="phoneExtension" type="text"  maxlength="5" 
                onkeyup="validateNextField(this,5,dsnPrefix);" 
                style="font-size:11px; width:25px;" title="Phone Extension" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
```

JavaScript Code

---

```
function validateFixedLengthNumericField(numericField, len){

    if (len != numericField.value.length){
        numericField.focus();   
        alert('Field must contain exactly '+len+' numbers.');
    }
}

// Once the max length is reached it forwards to the next field.
function validateNextField(numericField, len, nextField){

    if (len == numericField.value.length){
        nextField.focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to move forward to next field when max is reached and I want to validate that they have put the required info in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
document.getElementById('areaCode').addEventListener('keyup',function(){
    if(this.value.length == 3)
    {
        document.getElementById('phonePrefix').focus();
    }
},false);

document.getElementById('phonePrefix').addEventListener('keyup',function(){
    if(this.value.length == 3)
    {
        document.getElementById('phoneSuffix').focus();
    }
},false);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/wnSZQ/

Comment: I want it to validate that it is exactly that long and then do an alert or change the style if not.